# How to do override closeEvent functions to make it working

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm using pyside2 and pyqt5 lib to loading my UI file.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader

class A(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(A, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = QUiLoader().load('uiFile.ui')
    
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.ignore()


app = QApplication([])
mainWin = A()
mainWin.ui.show()
app.exec_()
```

In my thought, it will show '11111' when I clicked the X button.
However, it's not working at all.

[here is the ui file](http://sendanywhe.re/62RMYILC)

Comment: Can you add a code where you use the `operation_ui` class?

Comment: Can you update your question to contain the minimum reproducible code? It seems a bit hard to guess what's wrong if it's not running.

Comment: how about these?

Comment: Much better, but the content of "uiFile.ui" would help much.

Comment: Is it genuinely `print(11111111)` in your code? Because that is trying to print the value of a variable called `11111111` and not literal text. It should be `print('11111111')`.

Comment: I'm sure `print(111111)`  is not a problem. Because no one can use `closeEvent` function

Comment: Please, update your question with the working code, and also, update your initial code with all `import` statements. Answers are supposed to be used only for answers to the question, not for the question clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that "A" is a widget that is not displayed, it is not the window, so override closeEvent does not make sense. Instead you should use an event filter to monitor the window's events.

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import QEvent, QObject
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


class Manager(QObject):
    def __init__(self, ui, parent=None):
        super(Manager, self).__init__(parent)
        self._ui = ui

        self.ui.installEventFilter(self)

    @property
    def ui(self):
        return self._ui

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.ui:
            if event.type() == QEvent.Close:
                event.ignore()
                return True
        super().eventFilter(obj, event)


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    manager = Manager(QUiLoader().load("uiFile.ui"))
    manager.ui.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you want to override the closeEvent method of the QMainWindow used in the .ui then you must promote it and register it as [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128188/using-a-custom-pyside2-widget-in-qt-designer/52131384#52131384) shows.